# ANTLR: Parser rule sensitive to whitespace

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I have the following input data:

```
Valid string: "123A"
Invalid string: "123 A"

Valid string: "111A <= 5 AND 222A"
Invalid string: "111 A <= 5 AND 222A"
```

Below you can see the grammar I'm using (antlr 3.4).

```
my_id:  INT ('A'|'a') -> INT;
fragment DIGIT: '0' .. '9';
INT :   DIGIT+ ;
WS  :   (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

The problem is that `my_id` matches both `123 A` and `123A`. How can I throw a parsing error when detecting `123 A`?

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `123 A` is evaluated as `my_id` and not as `INT` and something else? Since the `INT` token is not a fragment, if you have a rule that accepts `A` it might be evaluated this way

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use another lexer item. Like `INTA : DIGIT+ ('A'|'a');`. This would only then cause problems if you use digits followed by an 'A' in another context.

Comment: @Benlitz I forgot to specify the ```WS``` which is the lexer rule that makes the grammar ignore the whitespace(s)

Comment: @StefanA how can i still convert INTA to an INT (```my_id:  INTA -> INT;```)? For ```123A``` I'm only interested in keeping ```123``` and trim the letter.

Comment: You can set the token type and the token text in the lexer rule (or parser rule / in an action / at tree contruction).

Comment: @StefanA, I'm pretty newbie with ANTLR. Would it be possible to help me with an example for this specific case for setting the token type in the lexer rule?

Comment: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Grammar+Design+Patterns shows some examples how to modify the text of tokens.